# How am i able to know, that my target group is an auto scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Suppose i create an auto scaling group and link a target group.

Is it possible to know from my target group if it is linked with an auto scaling group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the target group(s) linked to an autoscaling group:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names "NAME" --query 'AutoScalingGroups[].TargetGroupARNs[]'
```

if this is not empty, then there are one or more target groups associated to the autoscaling group.

You can retrieve the target group from the autoscaling group, but not the other way around.

Comment: Do you know, why this is not possible?